# Rails system tests fail when I manually name a label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

In a form, I manually named a label:

```
<%= f.label :name, "DEA License Number" %>
<%= f.text_field :dea_license_number, class: 'form-control'  %>
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<label for="dentist_detail_name">DEA License Number</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="dentist_detail[dea_license_number]" id="dentist_detail_dea_license_number" />
```

And my system test:

```
fill_in "DEA License Number", with: "999999"
```

When I run the tests, I get this:

```
Error:
SignUpJobSeekersTest#test_Sign_Up_Job_Seekers:
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible field "DEA License Number" that is not disabled
```

I'm at a bit of a loss. Thanks for supporting a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the generated HTML the `for` attribute of the label element doesn't match the `id` attribute of the input

```
'dentist_detail_name' != 'dentist_detail_dea_license_number'
```

therefore the label is not actually associated with the input (label must either wrap the input or `for` must match `id`).

Comment: Thanks Thomas for helping out a newbie. I'm grateful for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something wrong with your label. It should be

```
<%= f.label :dea_license_number, "DEA License Number" %>
```

Give that a try?